# Why am I getting an uninitialized constant error and how can I fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to run my signup form for a web app that I'm building in Rails, I get the following error:

uninitialized constant User::PillHQ

which references two methods in my app code, one in my user model and one in my user controller.

The method in question in the user model is

```
def save_with_payment
if valid?
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: PillHQ, card: stripe_card_token)
self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
save!
end
```

and the method in question in the user controller is

```
def create
@user = User.new(params[:user])
if @user.save_with_payment
sign_in @user
flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user)
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
else
render 'new'
end
end
```

I'm not sure how to remove the error, so any help you can give would be awesome!

Comment: It's an a project that I'm working on as my first web app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word `PillHQ` on the line below is not valid against "Naming Conventions", assuming it is a variable...

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: PillHQ, card: stripe_card_token)
```

> Local Variables
>   Lowercase letter followed by other characters, naming convention states that it is better to use underscores rather than camelBack for multiple word names, e.g. mileage, variable_xyz

More information can be found [here](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7/).